# cordova diagnostic plugin don't work

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

Im developing an app with phonegap and need to check if location is enable or disable, if disable, take the user to settings to turn it on. I found the cordova diagnostic plugin as a solution, but it doesn't work.
Here's my config.xml:

```
  <gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"/>
  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"/>
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.0.0" />
```

and the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDeviceReady() {

    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabledSetting(function(enabled){
            if(enabled)
            {
                alert("Location Setting is enabled");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Location Setting is disabled");
            }
        }, function(error){
            alert("The following error occurred: "+error);
        });
                }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
```

When I start the app from phonegap builder, nothing happens...

Comment: The plugin works fine when used correctly. What platform/device are you testing on? Have you connected a remote debugger to see if there are any errors logged in console? Or tried wrapping the call in a try/catch statement to catch and display exceptions?

Comment: Humm, i dont know nothing about that, its the first time im developing app... Could you tell me which  and how I use a debbuger? Thanks

Comment: Remote debugging guide: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/. `When I start the app from phonegap builder` - you are actually testing this on a device and not in the browser? Because it relies on **native** functionality, so will only work on an actual device (iPhone/iPad/iOS Simulator).